# How to get a non parametric one-dimensionnal regression of a function from several specimens obsevation

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction

### What I want to achieve

I am trying to get a prediction for an unknown function from several measurements done on several speciemens (function is actually a measurement along a specimen), **and a confidence interval associated with this prediction**.

### The data I have at my disposal

The data I have is shown on the image and consists of several points of measure along the specimen, and each point is actually the agregation of several measurements an i have access to the mean and standard error. I do not have acces to the raw measurements.

### What I tried

I tried to make a prediction using gaussian process regression using [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html) (see second example) but althought the prediction looks nice, the confidence interval does not reflect the dispersion of the measurements, and I'm obviously not using the tool the way it is meant to be used.

### Edit : data

just run this python to get a dictionnary of dataframes representing the data

```py
raw = {'7G2_faceAA': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 8.0,
   2: 22.0,
   3: 32.0,
   4: 44.0,
   5: 54.0,
   6: 64.0,
   7: 77.0,
   8: 93.0,
   9: 112.0,
   10: 132.0,
   11: 152.0,
   12: 175.0},
  'Y': {0: -26,
   1: -364,
   2: -545,
   3: -519,
   4: -521,
   5: -496,
   6: -363,
   7: -147,
   8: 112,
   9: 393,
   10: 431,
   11: 411,
   12: 427},
  'dY': {0: 19,
   1: 17,
   2: 11,
   3: 15,
   4: 17,
   5: 17,
   6: 30,
   7: 25,
   8: 27,
   9: 20,
   10: 26,
   11: 24,
   12: 21}},
 '7G2_faceAT': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 8.0,
   2: 22.0,
   3: 32.0,
   4: 44.0,
   5: 54.0,
   6: 64.0,
   7: 77.0,
   8: 93.0,
   9: 112.0,
   10: 132.0,
   11: 152.0,
   12: 175.0},
  'Y': {0: -179,
   1: -433,
   2: -475,
   3: -498,
   4: -491,
   5: -502,
   6: -333,
   7: -253,
   8: 245,
   9: 319,
   10: 417,
   11: 439,
   12: 461},
  'dY': {0: 26,
   1: 30,
   2: 22,
   3: 24,
   4: 23,
   5: 21,
   6: 27,
   7: 21,
   8: 28,
   9: 37,
   10: 21,
   11: 18,
   12: 13}},
 '7G2_faceBA': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 10.0,
   2: 19.0,
   3: 32.0,
   4: 39.0,
   5: 52.0,
   6: 64.0,
   7: 80.0,
   8: 95.0,
   9: 108.0,
   10: 133.0,
   11: 155.0},
  'Y': {0: -108,
   1: -336,
   2: -511,
   3: -530,
   4: -560,
   5: -559,
   6: -447,
   7: -368,
   8: -180,
   9: 97,
   10: 450,
   11: 436},
  'dY': {0: 25,
   1: 14,
   2: 20,
   3: 20,
   4: 22,
   5: 21,
   6: 33,
   7: 17,
   8: 13,
   9: 20,
   10: 25,
   11: 22}},
 '7G2_faceBT': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 10.0,
   2: 19.0,
   3: 32.0,
   4: 39.0,
   5: 52.0,
   6: 64.0,
   7: 80.0,
   8: 95.0,
   9: 108.0,
   10: 133.0,
   11: 155.0},
  'Y': {0: -272,
   1: -395,
   2: -503,
   3: -477,
   4: -494,
   5: -526,
   6: -410,
   7: -371,
   8: -145,
   9: 78,
   10: 440,
   11: 466},
  'dY': {0: 28,
   1: 25,
   2: 21,
   3: 14,
   4: 24,
   5: 13,
   6: 33,
   7: 22,
   8: 25,
   9: 36,
   10: 24,
   11: 17}},
 '8F2_faceAA': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 13.0,
   2: 22.0,
   3: 29.0,
   4: 41.0,
   5: 51.0,
   6: 59.0,
   7: 67.0,
   8: 78.0,
   9: 91.0,
   10: 105.0,
   11: 120.0,
   12: 139.0,
   13: 161.0,
   14: 185.0},
  'Y': {0: 24,
   1: -503,
   2: -577,
   3: -600,
   4: -599,
   5: -618,
   6: -595,
   7: -617,
   8: -474,
   9: -374,
   10: -185,
   11: 137,
   12: 282,
   13: 399,
   14: 389},
  'dY': {0: 25,
   1: 20,
   2: 15,
   3: 14,
   4: 8,
   5: 12,
   6: 18,
   7: 5,
   8: 16,
   9: 11,
   10: 21,
   11: 21,
   12: 14,
   13: 18,
   14: 13}},
 '8F2_faceAT': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 13.0,
   2: 22.0,
   3: 29.0,
   4: 41.0,
   5: 51.0,
   6: 59.0,
   7: 67.0,
   8: 78.0,
   9: 91.0,
   10: 105.0,
   11: 120.0,
   12: 139.0,
   13: 161.0,
   14: 185.0},
  'Y': {0: -122,
   1: -467,
   2: -479,
   3: -547,
   4: -556,
   5: -550,
   6: -525,
   7: -545,
   8: -401,
   9: -300,
   10: -120,
   11: 142,
   12: 360,
   13: 437,
   14: 462},
  'dY': {0: 37,
   1: 18,
   2: 22,
   3: 35,
   4: 23,
   5: 31,
   6: 29,
   7: 19,
   8: 21,
   9: 18,
   10: 14,
   11: 15,
   12: 20,
   13: 18,
   14: 22}},
 '8F2_faceBA': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 8.0,
   2: 23.0,
   3: 32.0,
   4: 41.0,
   5: 51.0,
   6: 63.0,
   7: 73.0,
   8: 88.0,
   9: 102.0,
   10: 119.0,
   11: 137.0,
   12: 158.0,
   13: 178.0},
  'Y': {0: 50,
   1: -329,
   2: -551,
   3: -522,
   4: -557,
   5: -536,
   6: -557,
   7: -467,
   8: -341,
   9: -153,
   10: 225,
   11: 289,
   12: 405,
   13: 479},
  'dY': {0: 34,
   1: 14,
   2: 22,
   3: 15,
   4: 25,
   5: 12,
   6: 25,
   7: 15,
   8: 15,
   9: 19,
   10: 20,
   11: 15,
   12: 21,
   13: 16}},
 '8F2_faceBT': {'X': {0: 0.0,
   1: 8.0,
   2: 23.0,
   3: 32.0,
   4: 41.0,
   5: 51.0,
   6: 63.0,
   7: 73.0,
   8: 88.0,
   9: 102.0,
   10: 119.0,
   11: 137.0,
   12: 158.0,
   13: 178.0},
  'Y': {0: -186,
   1: -305,
   2: -461,
   3: -477,
   4: -502,
   5: -462,
   6: -444,
   7: -389,
   8: -305,
   9: -99,
   10: 239,
   11: 381,
   12: 338,
   13: 460},
  'dY': {0: 34,
   1: 24,
   2: 27,
   3: 37,
   4: 32,
   5: 36,
   6: 24,
   7: 23,
   8: 32,
   9: 18,
   10: 15,
   11: 17,
   12: 15,
   13: 13}}}
mesures = {}
for key, val in raw.items():
    mesures[key] = pd.DataFrame(val)
```

[image: Data and attempt at prediction]

Comment: The posted image does not include the axis scales. If you can post an image with the values on both axes, I can extract the data from the image and try my hand at this.

Comment: I intentionnally cropped the ticks values as the problem is work related and the data is kinda confidential, but i'll post the data in arbitrary units ASAP